# Как безопасно передать данные

Tags: php, html, laravel

У меня есть контроллер отвечающий за создание отзыва продавцу, и есть реквест принимающий данные с формы, в самой форме я передаю ид юзера,ид продавца и ид товара через скрытый input, как можно заменить данные input'ы, потому-что в них можно тупо поменять значение в консоле, тем самым можно сделать отзыв другому продавцу.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ReviewRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'status' => 'required',
            'text' => 'required|max:162',
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'seller_id' => 'required',
            'product_id' => 'required',
        ];
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'status.required'=>'Вы не выбрали статус отзыва',
            'text.max'=>'Вы превысили количество символов в комментарии',
        ];
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Review;
use App\Http\Requests\ReviewRequest;

class ReviewController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(ReviewRequest $request)
    {

        $request['text'] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($request['text']));
        if(!Review::where('product_id',$request['product_id'])->exists()) {
            Review::create($request->validated());
            return back()->with('succes','Вы оставили отзыв');
        }
        return back(302);
    }
}
```

```
<form id="reviewForm" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('make-review') }}">
            @csrf
            {{ Form::hidden('user_id', Auth::user()->id) }}
            {{ Form::hidden('seller_id', $info->seller_id) }}
            {{ Form::hidden('product_id', $info->id) }}
            <div class="err-log hide align-items-center p-2">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group p-2">
                <label for="name" class="subLabel">Комментарий</label>
                <textarea rows="6" cols="10" id="name" style="width: 100%;" type="text" class="review-input" name="text"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="review-btns p-2">
                <input type="radio" value="0" id="negative-radio" name="status" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px">
                <label for="negative-radio" class="negative">
                    <img src="../img/down.png" id="img-negative" alt="">
                </label>
                <input type="radio" value="1" id="positive-radio" name="status" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px">
                <label for="positive-radio" class="positive">
                    <img src="../img/up.png" alt="" id="img-positive">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2">
                <button type="submit" class="log-btn">Создать</button>
            </div>
            
        </form>
```

Comment: А почему я не могу дать отзыв другому продавцу?

Comment: Вы к примеру купили товар у одного продавца, получается и отзыв можно оставить только тому продавцу у которого купили товар

Comment: Проверяйте на сервере что я купил этот товар у этого продавца.